# Labeling data based on a range of values in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Student ID' : [123456,789456,101112,131415],
                       'Balance': [26,10,11,27]})
```

I want to be able to create a new column called "Grade" and give code to the "Balance" column based on a range of values:

```
if Balance > 26 then Grade        = "Unsat" 
if Balance <= 10 then Grade       = "Excellent" 
If Balance is between 11&15 Grade = "Good" 
If Balance is between 16&25 Grade = "Moderate"
```

I wrote the below 2 line of code for the first 2 conditions and it worked fine , but I am stuck at the range from 11 to 15 & similarly any other ranges - not sure how to do that. Here is the code I wrote

```
df['Grade']=0
df.loc[df["Balance"]>26, ["Grade"]] = "Unsat"
df.loc[df["Balance"]<10, ["Grade"]] = "Excellent"
```

Comment: what do you want to do if the balance is 16~26?

Comment: @Chanhee .... I can give that a "Moderate" ..... I just want to know how to lebel that data if it is between a range of values

Comment: I think `pd.cut` is a little cleaner: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html. See the linked SO post above for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `np.select`

```py
df['Grade'] = np.select(
    [df['Balance'] > 26,
     df['Balance'] <= 10,
     df['Balance'].between(11, 15),
     df['Balance'].between(16, 25)],
    ['Unsat', 'Excellent', 'Good', 'Moderate'],
    np.nan
)
```

```
print(df)

   Student ID  Balance      Grade
0      123456       26        NaN
1      789456       10  Excellent
2      101112       11       Good
3      131415       27      Unsat
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grad = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['Balance'][i] > 26:
        grad.append('Unsat')
    elif 16 <= df['Balance'][i] <= 25:
        grad.append('Moderate')
    elif 11 <= df['Balance'][i] <= 15:
        grad.append('Good')
    elif 10 >= df['Balance'][i] :
        grad.append('Excellent')
    else : 
        grad.append(np.nan) #When conditions are not met
df['Grade'] = grad
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the contents of the if to suit your requirements:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Student ID': [123456, 789456, 101112, 131415], 'Balance': [26, 10, 11, 27]})


def t(x):
    balance = x["Balance"]
    if balance > 26:
        grade = "Unsat"
    elif balance >= 16:
        grade = "Moderate"
    elif balance >= 11:
        grade = "Good"
    else:
        grade = "Excellent"

    x["Grade"] = grade
    return x


df = df.apply(t, axis=1)
print(df)
```

OutPut：

```
   Student ID  Balance      Grade
0      123456       26   Moderate
1      789456       10  Excellent
2      101112       11       Good
3      131415       27      Unsat
```